Find a parsimonious logical combination of bit vectors
I have a set of bit vectors $x_i$ of the exact same length, each with a distinct bit pattern.
I have a target bit vector $t$ of the same length as the others, but with a distinct bit pattern.
I want to come up with a minimal logical combination of $x_i$ vectors (i.e., bitwise AND, OR, and NOT) such that the Hamming distance between the logical expression and $t$ is minimized. If it makes the formulation simpler, then we can express the Hamming distance as needing to be withing a given tolerance of $t$. In other words, as a constraint, where $d \leq d_{min}$.
There is a large cost associated with the use of additional $x_i$ vectors, so I want a solution that minimizes the use of distinct vectors. There is a negligible cost associated with more complicated logical expressions; a simplified one would be nice, but not mandatory. There is no additional cost if an expression uses a given vector more than once.
I believe that this is a logic optimization problem, but I'm unfamiliar with solvers in that area (which tend to be more focused on digital circuit design).

Scenario:
I tried to strip down my actual problem down to its mathematical properties. For those who want some context, imagine that I have a set of sensors that can detect the presence of different combinations of materials in a sample. The sensors are set, and are expensive, so I want to minimize how many I buy. They can detect different combinations of materials, in overlapping patterns in many cases. The sensors only come back as positive or negative; they don't indicate which materials that they detected; just that they detected one or more of the few that it is able to detect. I need to come up with a logical combination of these sensor readings to precisely detect just the materials that I am interested in. Once you have a reading from a sensor recorded, there's no cost in plugging it in many times to a logical function or formula.

By "minimal logical combination" do you mean either using the fewest $x$ vectors or having the fewest terms (assuming that an input vector can be used more than once)? If so, please clarify which. It will lead to a bicriterion model (the other criterion being minimizing Hamming distance).

Thanks for your comment. I added a paragraph explaining the relative importance of the criteria that I mentioned.

@taltman, is it possible to give a simple example of what exactly you are trying to do?

Given a solution A with zero Hamming distance but many vectors and a solution B with few vectors but a non-zero Hamming distance, which is preferable? Can you quantify preferences (e.g., an extra vector is justified if it reduces Hamming distance by 3 or more)?

@prubin Now that you have prodded me, I now see that I want to set a bound on the Hamming distance. Any solution with a Hamming distance of $d \leq d_{min}$ is acceptable. Would that help avoid a bicriterion model, as we now can just minimize the number of vectors? I will update the problem description.

@A.Omidi Thank you for your comment! I've tried to provide a bit of context at the bottom of my more mathematical description. I hope that is helpful.

I'll start with two disclaimers. First, while I will present an integer programming model, this problem might possibly be easier to solve using a constraint programming approach. Second, the practicality of the IP model will depend on the problem dimensions (mainly the number of sensors).
The IP model will rely on writing the approximation (denoted $q$) to the target $t$ in disjunctive normal form. Let $B$ be the dimension of a vector (number of bits) and $x^1,\dots,x^N$ the number of original vectors (corresponding to sensors). We will extend the set of $x$ vectors to $x^1, \dots, x^M$ ($M > N$) by computing the negations of the original vectors (e.g., $x^{N+1} = \neg x^1$) and all (or as many as possible) conjunctions of the original vectors and their negations. $M \approx 3^N$ since in any conjunction you can include for each $i$ either $x^i$, $\neg x^i$ or neither. If that gets too big, you can include only a subset of the possible conjunctions and live with an approximately maybe sort of optimal answer.
Once we are armed with all the $x$ vectors, we introduce binary variables $y_1,\dots, y_M$ indicating whether or not the corresponding $x$ vector is used in the approximation. We also introduce variables $q_1,\dots, q_B$ (can be binary or just nonnegative) to represent the resulting approximation of $t$ and nonnegative "slack/surplus" variables $u_1, \dots, u_B$ and $v_1, \dots, v_B$.
The objective function to be minimized is $$\sum_{i=1}^N y_i.$$ Note that we sum over only the first $N$ variables, corresponding to the original sensor vectors. To ensure that we count the use of those vectors correctly, we include constraints of the form $y_i \ge y_j$ for every combination of $i\in \lbrace 1,\dots, N\rbrace$ and $j$ such that $x^j$ is a conjunction involving $x^i$ or $\neg x^i.$
The approximation $q$ is defined by the constraints $$q_b \le \sum_{i=1}^M x^i_b y_i$$ and $$q_b \ge x^i_b y_i$$ for all $b = 1,\dots, B$ and, in the second case, for all $i=1,\dots, M.$ The second set of constraints can be condensed to the single constraint $$M q_b \ge \sum_{i=1}^M x^i_b y_i$$ at the risk of weakening the formulation.
Finally, to enforce the limit on Hamming distance, we add the constraints $$q_b + u_b - v_b = t_b \quad b=1,\dots,B$$ and $$\sum_{b=1}^B (u_b + v_b) \le d_{min}.$$

Thank you for that full formulation! Do I understand things correctly that you are saying that I need to instantiate the conjunction of every possible combination of two or more vectors among the set of vectors in the union of $x_i$ and $\neg x_i$? The values of $t_b$ and $q_b$ are binary, so I'm not sure exactly how to interpret the summation of $x^i_by_i$; is this using Boolean Algebra?

Yes to the first part (all possible conjunctions), although if $N$ is large you may have to settle for "most" of them (and a possibly suboptimal solution). The term $x^i_b y_i$ is the product of bit $b$ in vector $x^i$ (which is a parameter in the model) with binary variable $y_i$; so it is 1 if vector $x^i$ is part of the disjunction ($y_i=1$) and has a 1 in bit $b,$ 0 otherwise.
